# Printing int array consisiting of both numbers and letters

Tags: c, printf

I was writing a basic function in C to convert decimal integers to hexadecimal but I got confused in the combination of data types. and I am getting random numbers as output.

1. I know that both characters and numbers are there in the array, but only numbers are printing.
2. can the lines

```
char k=j+55;
bb[i] = k;
```

be improved?

below is the function

```
int decToHex(int b){
    int bb[50];
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(b!=0){
        j=b%16;
        if(j>9){
            char k=j+55;
            bb[i] = k;
        }
        else {
            bb[i] = j;
        }
        b = b/2;
        i++;
    }
    for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
        printf("%s",bb[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"%s"` is for strings, not integers.

Comment: @mr.loop - You write _convert decimal integers_, but what you're actually trying to convert is the internal representation of an integer, which is most probably not _decimal_.

Comment: sorry the %s was not in the original code. it was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you actually want to create an array of characters:

```c
char b[50];
```

It might be more clear to write

```c
char k = j - 10 + 'A';
```

And you probably want to replace

```c
// bb[i] = j
bb[i] = j + '0'
```

Division by 2 would be used for converting to binary, you need to divide by 16:

```c
// b = b / 2;
b = b / 16;
```

Finally, the output line should probably be

```c
printf("%c", bb[j]);
```

You might want to print a newline after the output loop:

```c
printf("\n");
```

The function signature expects an integer return, but I would need more information before I could tell you how to fix that. For now, we'll just return zero.

With these minimal changes, we get

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int decToHex(int b){
    char bb[50];
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(b!=0){
        j=b%16;
        if(j>9){
            char k = j - 10 + 'A';
            bb[i] = k;
        }
        else {
            bb[i] = j + '0';
        }
        b = b/16;
        i++;
    }
    for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
        printf("%c", bb[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    decToHex(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
3E8
```

Comment: yes, it works fine. though I still want to know if I have a general array that has both numbers and characters, how to print that.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to divide b to 16. because it's hex.

Second, if j <= 9, you need add '0'(ascii code 48) to j.

And your function returns nothing, so return type have to void. and bb[j] is char, not char[]. format string must be %c.

Solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void decToHex(int b) {
    int bb[50];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (b != 0) {
        j = b % 16;
        char k;
        if (j > 9) {
            k = j - 10 + 'A';
        } else {
            k = j + '0';
        }
        bb[i] = k;
        b = b / 16;
        i++;
    }
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        char c = bb[j];
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine. but if I remove `char c=bb[j]` and edit last to `printf("%c",bb[j])` , then (for ex) for 100, it prints the symbols on ASCII values of 6 and 4. while the code crashes for values where hexadecimal number should have alphabets. The first case is understandable but why does it not print those 6 alphabets even though they are characters themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array that can store `char` and `int`, we need a special type that can hold both. I chose a `struct` with a `union`:

**mixed_type.h**

```c
#ifndef MIXED_TYPE_H
#define MIXED_TYPE_H

typedef enum {
    CHAR = 0,
    INT
} type_t;

typedef struct {
    type_t type;
    union {
        int number;
        char letter;
    };
} entry_t;

#endif
```

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mixed_type.h"

void decToHex(int decimal) {
    int hex_digits = 0, copy_decimal = decimal;
    while (copy_decimal) { ++hex_digits; copy_decimal /= 16; }
    entry_t result[hex_digits];
    int index = hex_digits - 1;
    while (decimal) {
        int nibble = decimal % 16;
        if (nibble >= 10) {
            result[index].type = CHAR;
            result[index].letter = nibble - 10 + 'A';
        }
        else {
            result[index].type = INT;
            result[index].number = nibble;
        }
        --index;
        decimal /= 16;
    }
    for (index = 0; index < hex_digits; index++) {
        if (result[index].type == CHAR)
            printf("%c", result[index].letter);
        else
            printf("%d", result[index].number);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    decToHex(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
3E8
```

By putting the new type in a separate header file, we can make it easier to reuse.